# React Native Expo: auto play Audio sound

Tags: expo, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

hope you are having great day.

I am trying to play an audio list on click. every thing works just find . but when I continue pressing and reaching the last audio . it gives me this error

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_data.default[songIndex - 1].audio')]
```

the reason is that there in no file to play anymore in the array. now I want when I reach the last Item I should automatically start from the beginning.

```
  const goNext = async () => {
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync({
      uri: songs[songIndex + 1].audio,
    });

    setSound(sound);
    await sound.playAsync();
    slider.current.scrollToOffset({
      offset: (songIndex + 1) * width,
    });
  };
```

Comment: thank you it just works fine. the only problem when I reach the last item the audio is repeated but the images and titles are not how can I solve that slider.current.scrollToOffset({
      offset: (songIndex + 1) * width,
    });

Answer (score 0):

you should use `%` to repeat the music list

```
  const goNext = async () => {
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync({
      uri: songs[(songIndex + 1)%songs.length].audio,
    });

    setSound(sound);
    await sound.playAsync();
    slider.current.scrollToOffset({
      offset: (songIndex + 1)%songs.length * width,
    });
  };
```

Comment: thank you it just works fine. the only problem when I reach the last item the audio is repeated but the images and titles are not how can I solve that slider.current.scrollToOffset({
      offset: (songIndex + 1) * width,
    });